# How to uninstall a driver from recovery console

Tags: windows-8, drivers, system-recovery

I recently updated the "Standard AHCI Driver" (whatever it was called), to the one suggested on the laptop manufacturer's website.

At first, it kept going through the automatic recovery process. With much trouble, I managed to get the Windows 8 installation to boot into safe mode and stop it from automatically trying to fix startup (which was not working).

Now, when the computer restarts, it complains about iaStor.sys being invalid and / or missing. This makes sense, since the offending driver is causing all of these issues.

My question now- is there a way I can revert to the Standard AHCI Driver? Possibly using a recovery console? I want to avoid re-installing Windows, which is the only way I can see to fix this problem now.

Comment: You can [access System Restore](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/system-restore-from-windows-8-recovery-environment/) from WinRE. Also see [Rollback driver in Windows via command line](http://superuser.com/questions/200373/rollback-driver-in-windows-via-command-line), [Windows Repair Disc - Rollback a driver from Windows Command Prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/310351/windows-repair-disc-rollback-a-driver-from-windows-command-prompt-windows-in), [Can I uninstall faulty drivers through System Recovery Mode command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/324468/can-i-uninst) etc.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into following error with `pnputil -e` on the latest Windows 10 repair console:

```
No published driver packages were found on the system
```

I had to use `dism`

Listing drivers:

```
dism /image:c:\ /get-drivers
```

Removing a driver:

```
dism /image:c:\ /remove-driver /driver:oem#.inf
```

Use `list vol` inside `diskpart` to get the assigned drive letter of your windows partition and replace /image:**c**:\ with it

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing the offending driver is not shown in Device Manager while in Safe Mode?
If it is shown, you should be able to rollback or install the standard driver from there.

Otherwise, from Safe Mode (and possibly the recovery console), you can use `pnputil.exe` to uninstall the driver.

Type `pnputil -e` to show a list of installed drivers.
You may want to use `pnputil -e | more` so the list is output one screen at a time.
After you've located the driver in the list, note the inf file shown for the driver (e.g., `oem00.inf`).
Type `pnputil -d oem00.inf` to delete the driver.
You may need to use `pnputil -f -d oem00.inf` to force deletion.

Comment: If the `pnputil` is not available in the console make sure you change the current directory from `X:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: I've just tried pnputil -e in a windows 10 recovery console. The command works, but shows only three entries. This is suspicious and most likely the installed drivers of the recovery console itself. The current directory was 'C:\Windows\System32'